# Cannot show floating Window after user sign in

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I coded the Floating Window feature by following HMS developer guide, everything is in place, but after sign in by Huawei ID, the floating window does not show up, could anyone help?

```
private void showFloatWindowNewWay() {
    if (!hasInit) {
        init();
    }
    Games.getBuoyClient(this).showFloatWindow();
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showFloatWindowNewWay();
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

•   If the user's phone runs EMUI of a version earlier than 9.1.1, after the init API is called, call the showFloatWindow API in the onResume method and call the hideFloatWindow API in the onPause method. The hideFloatWindow API can be called only after the showFloatWindow API has been called to display the game floating window on the game UI. For details, please refer to Floating Window.

•   If the user's phone runs EMUI 9.1.1 or a later version, use the new floating window display scheme. HMS Core displays the floating window in floating dock mode. Users can swipe right to display the floating window. If the floating window is not displayed, instruct the user to search AppAssistant under Settings, tap Game Space, and add the game to Game Space.